# What kind of tree produces these seed pods looking like spiky balls?

Tags: plants, trees, tree-identification

I recently moved to southern Virginia near the coast (about 15 miles in from it).  All over the ground are these spiky balls that I assume contain seeds to the tree they fall off of.

There are literally thousands of these things on the ground. When they first fell, they were green in color. I would have grabbed a picture of the bark of the tree, but the tree that dropped these is covered in some sort of ivy vine that's growing up it and I couldn't get a good picture of the bark.  The trees aren't near any water sources.

[image: seed pod]
[image: seed pods on ground]

Comment: What does the seed (or seeds) inside look like?

Comment: Some of our older neighbors refer to the balls as "sputniks."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is a [sweet gum tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquidambar_styraciflua).

> The distinctive compound fruit is hard, dry, and globose,1–1.5 inches (25–38 mm) in diameter, composed of numerous (40-60) capsules.[13] Each capsule, containing one to two small seeds, has a pair of terminal spikes (for a total of 80-120 spikes). When the fruit opens and the seeds are released, each capsule is associated with a small hole (40-60 of these) in the compound fruit.
>
> Fallen, opened fruits are often abundant beneath the trees; these have been popularly nicknamed "burr (or bir) balls",[14] "gum balls",[19] "space bugs", "monkey balls", "bommyknockers", "sticker balls",[20] or "goblin bombs".

[Source.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquidambar_styraciflua#Fruit)

See this [page](http://www.eattheweeds.com/sweet-gum-tree/) for an almost identical picture of the spiky ball and this [one](http://dendro.cnre.vt.edu/dendrology/syllabus/factsheet.cfm?ID=53) (via @Sue) to show the range which means that they are definitely in Virginia.